# Log in programmatically and redirection

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

This is code which is responsible for log in user and redirect to specific place. But there is a problem, after redirection im not logged in, firewall stops me and redirects me to the login page. When i press F5 everything is ok, i'm logged in.

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('some_route'));

/**
 * @var $loginManager LoginManager
 */
$loginManager = $this->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');
$loginManager->loginUser('main', $client, $response);

/**
 * @var $eventDispatcher EventDispatcher
 */
$userEvent = new UserEvent($user, $request);
$eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN, $userEvent);

return $response;
```

When i use forwarding instead of redirect everything is ok.

```
$response = $this->forward('AcmeExampleBundle:Controller:index');
```

Any suggestions?